# is using a dependency inside a object's prototype method bad?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple app that retrieves youtube song data from a database, and have it displayed on a list.

Here's what the Track object looks like basically:

```
function Track(title, artist, genre, length, videoId) {
  this.title = title;
  this.artist = artist;
  this.genre = genre;
  this.length = length;
  this.videoId = videoId;
}
```

Note: videoId is simply a unique character string that is used by the player.

Now, I create some module with a public API that handles all the youtube player functionality. Something like below:

```
var player = (function() {

  function playVideo(videoId) {
    youtubePlayer.playVid(videoId);
  }

  // ... other player functionality ...

  return {
    playVideo: function(videoId) {
       return playVideo(videoId);
    }
  }

})();
```

(I'm just making up youtube's API above, I forget what the actual code to play a video is, but it's something similar)

Now, I want to add a function to the Track object that will play THAT track. I'll be calling this method when the user clicks the play button for that track. Something like below:

```
Track.prototype.playVideo = function(player) {
  player.playVideo(this.videoId);
}
```

Basically, I'm passing in the 'player' module I created into the prototype method, and then using it to play that specific Track's video using the API.

Is this okay to do, or is it considered bad practice? Essentially, it's creating a dependency on an outside module inside a prototype property.

If this IS bad practice, what would be the better way to approach this issue?

Thanks for any insight into this :)

Comment: as coded, there is no outside dependency, you bring all you need into the function with arguments.

Comment: yes, you're right :) I guess I should have said something along the lines of using outside code? Anyways, is this bad practice in any way?

Comment: it's not bad at all, DI is a good pattern. i should mention though that if you make "videoId" a property of player, you could use the player's method on the track, so you could just write your last code as Track.prototype.playVideo = player.playVideo; instead of using an extra wrapper. i like recycling.

Comment: very nice! that does look much cleaner, thanks @dandavis ! :)

Comment: If I were you, I would not put function `playVideo` in Track.prototype. Because your Object Track itself CANNOT play.  In your design, you may also need to add more to Track, like `sell`, `buy`, etc. These are business logic. I would just play it like: `player.playVideo(track)`.

Comment: @CaiShaojiang, so basically what dandavis said on his second comment? Or are you referring to something different?

Comment: Oh, I am referring to a different issue. I mean, the design itself, may be modified. The current implementation, from my point of view, is a bit 'reversed'. I would put the `play`, which is a 'verb', inside some object that can 'do' something, not `Track`.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. Thanks for the insight! :)